# How can I remove a Lego 4x4 plate from a non-Lego baseplate?

Tags: disassembly

I have tried using a brick separator, prying with fingers, bending the plate and stacking bricks on it.

Comment: Hi @CluelessLegoenthusiastically and welcome to Bricks.SE! If you can, please upload a picture so we can see what sort of baseplate you're faced with - the type, thickness and positioning might all offer possible solutions. Meanwhile check out the [tour] and [help] pages to learn more about the community, its rules and customs here. Play well!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried combining the already tried approaches? For example, adding some 2x4 bricks on the plate to act as a lever (in the direction of the longer side of the 2x4s), then bend the plate and the baseplate in different directions and slip the edge of a brick separator in the (hopefully) revealed space between the plate and baseplate.